# Don't show any text or error in reactive object in body of the email in Shiny

Tags: r, email, shiny, shinydashboard

I'd like to send an email (at this moment using `blastula` package) and the body of the message is a reactive object (`MyMSG()`) create in:

```
MyMSG <- reactive({

output$text_output <- renderText({input$text_input})

})
```

But a don't have success in export the text inside my `textAreaInput` inside the email body. In my example:

```
observeEvent(input$sendMSG, {
  
  output$sendMSG <- MyMSG() 
    my_email_object<- 
    compose_email(
      body = c(MyMSG())
    )
```

But the body of the message is empty or if I change something (eg. `as.vector(MyMSG())` or `readLines(MyMSG())`) an "Error in writeImpl: Text to be written must be a length-one character" error.

Please, any ideas to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
MyMSG <- reactive({
  output$text_output <- renderText({input$text_input})
})
```

is not correct. Simply do

```
output$text_output <- renderText({input$text_input})
```

And for your observer:

```
observeEvent(input$sendMSG, {
  my_email_object <- 
    compose_email(
      body = input$text_input
    )
```

Comment: Thanks again @Stéphane Laurent good solution and the problem was solved!!